# How to fix TFS build with Visual Studio 2019 x64-bit

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, 64-bit

MSBuild x64bit in Visual Studio 2019 works alright.

As executing MSBuild in Visual Studio, MSBuild locates:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe

However, when running TFS Build, there is an error about "AxImp.exe" missing.

I am sure that I have Windows STKs installed when I installed Visual Studio.

Here is a snapshot of my .csproj property:

> Project="$(MSBuildExtensionPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props"
>   Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')"

The TFS build agent resides on the same host having that same Visual Studio.

Here are the build definitions which are defined on TFS server:

- MSBuild Version: Latest (or MSBuild 15.0 MSBuild 14.0 or MSBuild 12.0
  or MSBuild 4.0)
- MSBuild Architecture: MSBuild x64

When building the solution through TFS build, there is an error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5):
>   Error MSB3091: Task failed becaused "AxImp.exe" was not found, or the
>   correct Mcrosoft Windows SDK is not installed.  The task is looking
>   for "AxImp.exe" in the bin subdirectory beneath the loaction specified
>   in the InstallationFolder value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86.

The log in TFS build shows that msbuild execution is located from:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

Comment: Something odd with that name AxImp.exe, I think it's the same name as a component in the 90's. Nevertheless the way to troubleshoot is to run ProcMon during the build and see where it's looking for the AxImp.exe - check it exists and has permission. If not find the exe / download it and put it where it's expected.

Comment: I don't understand why the error originates from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2015,5) requirement which I have no control over this file.  I find AxImp.exe but don't know where the system expects it to be at.  Are there any other ways to find out where it expects AxImp.exe besides using ProcMon?

Comment: Another question: Why TFS picks C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe to run.

In TFS build defintion, I specify MSBuild run as I set "Specify Location" -> Path to MSBuild -> Point to MSBuild in Visual Studio. 
However, it always comes back to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\

Comment: It's probably this problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9122

Comment: You can manually specify the path to msbuild in the build definition to work around this issue

Comment: @riQQ: I set the path to msbuild in the build definition, but when running, TFS somehow gets back to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the msbuild step in the build definition?